# Does this sentence "iPhone 2G has Photo Geotagging capacity of No" make any sense?

Tags: meaning

Ok, this is the original sentence:

> iPhone 2G does not have Photo Geotagging capacity.

I want to rewrite it as *iPhone 2G has Photo Geotagging capacity of No*.

So my question is does the sentence

> iPhone 2G has Photo Geotagging capacity of No.

make any sense (that is correct grammar & can be accepted by the reader)?

Comment: The original sentence is much better than either of your rewrite suggestions. If you must rewrite it then `The iPhone 2G does not support Photo Geotagging` would be understandable.

Comment: but i have no choice, i have to use the 2nd form

Comment: If you have no choice then I'm afraid you are stuck with a sentence that isn't as easily understandable as the original. Your rewrite leads the reader to believe that it does have Photo Geotagging capacity right up until they read the word 'No'. I still understand it but it's not as simple as the original.

Comment: You could say `The iPhone 2G has no Photo Geotagging capacity`

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU.

Comment: Quite apart from the grammaticality of the sentence, there is no such thing as an iPhone 2G. The second iPhone model released was the ***iPhone 3G***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rewritten sentence does not make much sense. The meaning will probably be understood by most readers, but it feels extremely awkward, and sound like something badly translated by a machine, not someone a human who speaks English will write. This is because you either have the capacity for something or you don't, but your phrasing suggests that you *do* have the capacity, with a value of "no". It's like, when asked (for instance) what revision of Bluetooth a phone supports, you can say "Bluetooth version 3" or "Bluetooth version 4", but you can't say "Bluetooth version No" - you can say "Does not have Bluetooth". The rejection of a category isn't a value in that category.

If, as you mentioned in the comments, you're forced to change the structure, perhaps removing several words will make it from a badly structured *sentence* to a *list item*:

> iPhone 2g Photo Geotagging capability: No

You keep the [Capability] - [Value] format, but formatted as a list of specifications, which works a lot better.

Comment: ok, "I don't have capacity of writing" & I has writing capacity of no" why the second does not make any sense?

Comment: +1 for reduction to the logical contradiction "The rejection of a category isn't a value in that category.", as opposed to some arbitrary stricture of English syntax.